# Can I open one template/route when Craft is offline?

Tags: routes, system-status

I've set Craft offline (System status). Is it possible to "open" one specific URL route so it can be accessed even though the website is offline?

For example the route: `/blog/post`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "open" more than one route, have a look at this question:
[Can I open templates/routes other than 503 when Craft is offline?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13639/can-i-open-templates-routes-other-than-503-when-craft-is-offline)

Comment: Fair enough. I'll accept this solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a template called `503.html` to your `/templates` folder. Craft will then use that template whenever the system is turned off, due to the HTTP status being set to `503` (service unavailable).

Inside the `503.html` template, you can of course include another template (e.g. `blog/post`).