# Can I open templates/routes other than 503 when Craft is offline?

Tags: routes, system-status

I've set Craft offline (System status). Is it possible to "open" URL routes so it can be accessed even though the website is offline? Right now every request gets routed to my 503.html page.

For example the routes: `/impressum` and `/about`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using the System Status switch in Settings → General.

I had a similar requirement and solved it with a custom variable "maintenanceMode" in my config.php and added some simple logic to the `init` method in my business logic plugin, which redirects all request except some maintenance mode URLs to the 503 page.

```php
$maintenanceUrls = array('/503', '/impressum', '/about');

if (craft()->request->isSiteRequest() && craft()->config->get('maintenanceMode')) {
    if (!in_array(craft()->request->getUrl(), $maintenanceUrls)) {
        craft()->request->redirect('503');
    }
}
```